# ASP.NET IIS change APP_DATA and Bin folders

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Is there a way to tell ASP not to look for dlls in BIN folder?

ASP.NET automatically replace |DataDirectory| with a path ending with \App_Data is there a way to change that?

I never searched so much with so meager results.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP - this is ASP.NET. Can you edit your question and retag, please?

Comment: No, there is not. Why would you want this?

Comment: @JohnSaunders working with relative path always prepends App_Data so i must place my things in app_data..

Comment: What does this have to do with the bin folder?

Comment: @JohnSaunders cause i cannot move my dll anywhere else cause ASP.NET looks for assemblies in \bin (at least i am facing that)

Comment: I meant what does relative path and App_Data have to do with bin? I'm asking about your comment, above. The DLLs have _always_ had to be in `bin`, since Day 1. You just need to get used to that part and move on.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry John you are missing the point of my question and not being useful. If this cannot be done i'm ok with that.

Comment: Ok, I guess maybe you're just putting two things together that have little to do with each other. You can't change either one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders my core problem in a nutshell is i can't find a way to point to my SQLCE database that is placed outside my ASP deploy folder cause a path with "APP_DATA" is always resolved. I need a relative path. Guess this can't be done either

Comment: Is your database located within your site? Then you can use a relative path. Just don't use |DataDirectory|. If it's outside the site, then you should be using SQL Server Express or else SQL Server LocalDB.

Comment: It Is inside my site but it seems like a i can only navigate down the folder-tree. I will try something and open a new more specific question about that if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, for both questions.

Both **bin** and **|DataDirectory|** are hard-wired in the ASP.NET runtime, there is no way to change it.

If you don't want to use `\App_Data`, just don't use it and don't use `DataDirectory` either. Use your own data location and implement your own code to get to it.

There is simply no way around the `bin` directory.